# Power BI (dax) - Categorize records if search term exists

Tags: search, powerbi, dax, lookup, contains

I have been unable to find an answer to this that returns consistent and properly chosen results.  I hope someone can help.

In Power BI, I have two tables.  The "_Inc Look In Fields" column in the "Incident" table contains long text strings (some 500K records) and a "Keyword" column where this formula will go.  "Lookup - Conferencing" contains a list of text strings, which may or may not include a second search term and may or may not contain an exclusion term and the keyword value in the "Return" column.  There are over 120 combos in this table.

**Lookup - Conferencing** table (120+ rows)

[image: Table 2]

**Incidents** table (500K+ rows)

[image]

The tables are unrelated and contain no value common to both.

I need a formula that searches the Incident table for the **first term(s)** listed in the Lookup table, excluding anything in the Exclude column, and for the first match it finds from the Lookup table, enter the "Return" value in the Keyword column.  It can then move on to the next row in Incident, etc.  It should not continue searching for matching combos once it finds the first matching combo.

I have a formula now that does this (thank you to Alexis Olson) but there are 2 problems and I've already bugged Alexis enough.

[image]

I think the formula is telling it to compare each of the 120+ rows of the Lookup table to the row in Incident it's looking at (thus, going through the Look in Field 120+ times) and then selects the Maxx or Minx of that list of results (I've tried it using both options, Minx and Maxx).  That isn't very efficient (causes it to calculate over 60M combos), so it's very slow. But, more than that, I can't figure out what it views as Minx or Maxx (is it the number of characters in the Return value, is the number of characters in the search combo, or is it arbitrary, etc.?).  So it's not always returning the first matching combo and thus, is skewing my results.

So I either need an adjustment made to Alexis' formula or a different one.

**Can anyone help?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can check this solution:

```
KEYWORD =  TOPN (
        1,
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            FILTER (
                ADDCOLUMNS (
                    GENERATE ( VALUES ( Incidents[_Inc Look In Fields] ), VALUES ( lookup_tab ) ),
                    "HitLookup",
                        (
                            CONTAINSSTRING ( Incidents[_Inc Look In Fields], lookup_tab[Search For Term 1] )
                                && CONTAINSSTRING ( Incidents[_Inc Look In Fields], lookup_tab[Search For Term 2] )
                        )
                            && (
                                NOT (
                                    CONTAINSSTRING ( Incidents[_Inc Look In Fields], lookup_tab[Exclude Term 1] )
                                )
                                    || lookup_tab[Exclude Term 1] == ""
                            )
                ),
                [HitLookup]
            ),
            "Return", [Return]
        )
    )
```

[image]
Internal table produce this:
[image]

[image]

We need to tick "Show rows without data" (Select visualization -> Right-click on the data field and select show item with no data)

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the formula.  In particular: (1) I assume "lookup_tab" = the table that contains the search, exclude and return fields.  Is that correct?  (2) What is "HitLookup"?  (3) Is the whole thing supposed to be a column formula (so I need to add "column name =" at the beginning)?  (4) Are there supposed to be two "=" after "Exclude Term 1"?  (5) Can you explain what the formula is doing in general?

Comment: Note:  When I made the changes noted in my previous comment associated with #1 and #3, every row was assigned the same Return value that was neither the first return item on the list, nor the first alphabetically.  Also, where am I supposed to "tick "Show rows without data""?

Comment: My "lookup_tab" is your example "Lookup - Conferencing". "HitLookup" is a boolean value True/False, using to filter set. Yes you need to add "column name = " at the beginning. (3) it should be a measure; (4) its depend if you have Nulls read this:
https://dax.guide/op/equal-to/
https://dax.guide/op/strictly-equal-to/
(5) We generate for each unique incident a set of rows from lookup_tab and we check if the condition is met.

I also update my answer.

Comment: I still don't understand.  (A) Is this a column formula or a measure? I need it to be a column.  (B) The original formula caused every row to return the same value.  The formula in your screenshot (which is different than the original) produces this error: "The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value."  (C) I'm also concerned about efficiency because your screenshots indicate it produces the internal table for each row.  I'd prefer it stop examining the row as soon as it results in "True" and giving me "Return", then do the next row, etc.

Comment: This is a measure, I don't see in your question that you need a CalculatedColumn;Why CalcColumn??; I show you an internal table to better understanding what is going on. Working on set is faster than looping through all rows one by obe (DAX doesn't have loop/break condition). You shoud use original code anything else is only for explanation purposes.

Comment: (1) I need to categorize as many of the 500K records as possible based on various terms used in the short descriptions.  Icon, button, add in, etc. all roll up to Icon/Button.  Password, access, log, authorization, etc. all roll up to Access. And so on. That categorization is then charted and/or the data table is exported.  I need the category assigned to each ticket to go with that export.  (2) The original code isn't working...all 500K record gets assigned "Application" (one of my possible results).

Comment: Keyword = TOPN(1,SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(ADDCOLUMNS(GENERATE(VALUES(Incidents[_Inc Look In Fields]), VALUES('Lookup - BasicKeywords')),"HitLookup",(CONTAINSSTRING( Incidents[_Inc Look In Fields], 'Lookup - BasicKeywords'[Search For Term 1]) && CONTAINSSTRING(Incidents[_Inc Look In Fields], 'Lookup - BasicKeywords'[Search For Term 2])) && (NOT(CONTAINSSTRING( Incidents[_Inc Look In Fields], 'Lookup - BasicKeywords'[Exclude Term 1])) || 'Lookup - BasicKeywords'[Exclude Term 1] == "")),[HitLookup]),"Return", [Return]))

Comment: Is that right?  (Yes, it's using a different table).

Comment: correct; For CalculateColumn you can try: 
Keyword2 = CALCULATETABLE(TOPN(1,SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(ADDCOLUMNS(GENERATE(VALUES(Incidents[_Inc Look In Fields]), VALUES('Lookup - BasicKeywords')),"HitLookup",(CONTAINSSTRING( Incidents[_Inc Look In Fields], 'Lookup - BasicKeywords'[Search For Term 1]) && CONTAINSSTRING(Incidents[_Inc Look In Fields], 'Lookup - BasicKeywords'[Search For Term 2])) && (NOT(CONTAINSSTRING( Incidents[_Inc Look In Fields], 'Lookup - BasicKeywords'[Exclude Term 1])) || 'Lookup - BasicKeywords'[Exclude Term 1] == "")),[HitLookup]),"Return", [Return])))

Comment: Still not working.  The keyword "Application" was correctly applied to the results but none of the other keywords were applied.  So the calculation ignored the 49 possible keyword matches that preceded it and the other 48 possible matches that came after it.

Comment: Are you out of ideas?  I still would really like to get this to working!